# Tab bar Items not showing properly

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4

[image: Picture]

Figure 1 displays a dynamically created tab bar controller that was loaded when the application starts:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    autoMagically = [[AutoMagically alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [self.window addSubview:autoMagically.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

if i load it by clicking a button on a view (the way i want and need to do it) i get whats shown in figure 2 of the picture above:

```
-(void) loadWhenClicked{
AutoMagically  *todaysDeal = [[AutoMagically alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    todaysDeal.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:todaysDeal animated:YES];
    [todaysDeal release];

}
```

Heres my code for creating the tab bar:

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

FirstViewController* vc1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];

SecondViewController* vc2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

vc1.title = @"Dallas";//[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Citynamefrmhome"];
vc1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Dealss.png"];

vc2.title = @"My Vouchers";
vc2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_voucher_S.png"]; 

NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1,vc2, nil];

tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;

[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

How do i make the tab bar controller show properly like in figure 1 when i load it like i would any other view?
This is an iphone view based app using xcode 4.

Comment: I meant http://troycomptonworld.com/error/figure3.png sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is UITabController is a view controller so it's not really something you want add to the display with addSubview (since it's not a view). Instead, mod your code to do this and you'll be fine:

```
UITabBarController *todaysDeal = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

FirstViewController* vc1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];

SecondViewController* vc2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

vc1.title = @"Dallas";//[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Citynamefrmhome"];
vc1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Dealss.png"];

vc2.title = @"My Vouchers";
vc2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_voucher_S.png"]; 

NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1,vc2, nil];

todaysDeal.viewControllers = controllers;

todaysDeal.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:todaysDeal animated:YES];
[todaysDeal release];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello and thanks for responding. I'm creating the tab bar controller in viewDidLoad. Do i keep this code in there? Also, I dont see where the tab bar controller is being added to the view. You create it, then it transitions as if its calling another view to load. Please excuse my lack of knowledge on this.

Comment: The problem is if you're adding this in viewDidLoad, you're creating a UIViewController whenever you create a UIViewController. It's just not necessary. So basically just use the UITabBarController as your only UIViewController ... there's no need to have the AutoMagically at all. Make sense?

Comment: It worked!! I didnt realize a tab bar controller was a view controller in itself. I have asked this question and never  got an answer till now. Thank you!! I will buy you lunch or even send you something via PayPal. I have worked on this for 2 days. Thank you!!

Comment: Cool, i'd settle for you you voting up my answer though ;)